# How can I apply the results of groupby command to all rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

[image]

I want to have the max of the 'Sell_price' column according to 'Date' and 'Product_id' columns, without losting the dimension of dataframe as:

[image]

Since my data is very big, without a doubt using 'for' command is not logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['Sell_price'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Product_id'])['Sell_price'].transform('max')
```